# Full screen scroll (IOS)

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, phonegap-build

I have made an iOS application using `PhoneGap Build`, Which works fine. I am having some kind of problem while scrolling a page. When I scroll from bottom or from Top whole screen moves. Is there any way to prevent this,as I know this is `iOS` feature. Which is very nice but in case of my application I do not want this. So help me out.

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details? I guess your TabBar is inside your scrollview... But that's just guessing since I can't see the code or the xib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in you config file:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />

<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```